# CRUD operations are not applying to Database kendo ui web

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo grid to show Employee data and also to perform create,update and delete.Read operation is performing nice but coming to the remaining three operations are not reflecting back to database

here is the code which i have tried

```
<div id="grdCRUD">
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
 dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "GridWebService.asmx/GetData"
                },
                update: {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: function (EmpNames) {
                        return "GridWebService.asmx/UpdateEmp" + EmpNames.eid
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                destroy: {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "GridWebService.asmx/DeleteEmp"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 6,
            schema: {
                data: "d",
                model: {
                    id: "eid",
                    fields: {
                        ename: { validation: { required: true} },
                        age: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                        salary: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        $("#grdCRUD").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            height: 300,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                                    { field: "ename", title: "EmployeeName", width: "150px" },
                                    { field: "age", title: "EmployeeAge", width: "150px" },
                                    { field: "salary", title: "EmployeeSalary", width: "100px" },
                                    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "210px" }
                                 ],
            editable: "popup"
        });
 });
</script>
```

here my web service

```
[WebMethod]
public List<EmpNames> GetData()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Emp", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "emp");
    return LstEmpNames(ds);
}

public List<EmpNames> LstEmpNames(DataSet ds)
{
    List<EmpNames> objenamelst = new List<EmpNames>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        EmpNames objemp = new EmpNames();

        objemp.eid = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
        objemp.ename = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
        objemp.age = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]);
        objemp.salary = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3]);
        objenamelst.Add(objemp);
    }
    return objenamelst;
}
[WebMethod]
public DataSet DeleteEmp(int id)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete  Emp where eid=" + id, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return null;
}

[WebMethod]
public DataSet CreateEmp()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Emp values", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return null;
}

[WebMethod]
public DataSet UpdateEmp(int eid)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update emp set ename='SHANKI',age=25,salary=6000 where eid=1", con);
    con.Close();
    return null;
}
```

is anything i have missed or if the code is wrong can you provide me any sample code is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully working CRUD application which is using an ASP.NET web service: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-web-service-crud

The problem with your implementation is the signature of the methods - check the linked example how the methods should look like.

A detailed explanation about invoking ASP.NET web services from JavaScript can be found in this excellent blog post: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Comment: thanks for quick replay.I'm looking for html page not for the asp page as we are developing the application completely in html pages.Based on Html can you provide me any sample code as you provide for asp.net

Comment: Hello Korchev i have taken .html page and web service.I am binding values from DB to Grid through Web service.But the problem is i am not able to do update and delete,Insert operations.Make sure i am not using Ajax binding,Just using normal data source.

Comment: @parsanamoni sorry, how is this related to the original question?